# Impact of compression codec in Azure Data Lake

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-data-lake

It's clear and well documented that the ability to split zip files has a big impact on the performance and parallelisation of jobs within Hadoop.

However Azure is built upon Hadoop and there is no mention of this impact anywhere that I can find in the Microsoft documentation.

Is this not an issue for ADL?

Is, for example, GZipping large files an acceptable approach now or am I going to run into the same issues of inability to parallelise my jobs due to choice of compression codec?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that Azure Data Lake Analytics is **not** based on Hadoop.

RojoSam is correct that GZip is a bad compression format to parallelize over.

U-SQL does recognize .gz files automatically and does decompress them. However, there is a 4GB limit on the size of the compressed file (since we cannot split and parallelize processing it) and we recommend that you use files in the area of a few 100MB to 1GB.

We are working on adding Parquet support. If you need other compression formats such as BZip: please file a request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback.

Comment: That's great. Thank you very much.

Is ADLA built totally in house?

Comment: Mostly. The scale out engine is based on Microsoft Dryad, the current resource manager is based on YARN (and our team is one of the main contributors to YARN).

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to start reading a GZip file from a random position. It is necessary to start always reading from the beginning.

Then, if you have a big GZip (or other not splittable compression format), you can not read/process ***blocks*** of it in parallel, ending processing all the file sequential in only one machine.

The main idea of Hadoop (and other Big data alternatives) relies on process data in parallel in different machines. A big GZip file doesn't match with this approach.

There are some data formats that allows compress ***data pages*** using Gzip and keep the file splittable (each page can be processed in different machines, but each GZip block continues requiring be processed in only one machine) like Parquet.